# ScalaTest: sharing resource between tests

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala-cats

For my integration tests I need to create and destroy resources when every tests ran (for example starting and stopping docker images to test against).

Creating a resource can take time so I'd like to do it once for every tests that needs it and destroy it when it's not needed anymore.

For now I've done that by creating the resource lazily and adding a shutdown hook  :

```scala
object MyResource {
  lazy val singleton = {
    val docker = Await.result(startImage(), 1 minute)
    sys.addShutdownHook(Await.result(docker.stop(), 1 minute))
    docker
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a better way to handle that like fixture but I'm not sure that I can start and stop the docker image once with that.

My tests are in multiple classes, so I can't use beforeAndAfterAll (and I'd like to avoid using Await.result).

Comment: Why don't you use [**testcontainers**](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-scala)?

Comment: Hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I didn't this project, I'll give it a look thx! Also I'll update my description as it was not clear docker image is one example of resources I need to manage.